# Java If-Statement short form

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, short

I found the following code:

```
  static void CreatePartys(int n) 
{ 

    int num = 0;
    int[] e = new int[n];
    e[num] = n;

    while (true) 
    { 
         int part = 0; 
        count = count +1;

        while (num >= 0 && e[num] == 1) 
        { 
            part += e[num]; 
            num--; 
        } 

        if (num < 0)  return; 

        e[num]--; 
        part++; 

        while (part > e[num]) 
        { 
            e[num+1] = e[num]; 
            part = part - e[num]; 
            num++; 
        } 

        e[num+1] = part; 
        num++; 
    } 
}
```

And I'm stuck at the if-Statement, I've seen this never before, not even inside a Java-Book.

```
 if (num < 0)  return;
```

What does it return? true, false, a number?

Comment: It returns from the method. And it returns nothing, since its declared as a void method.

Comment: It just returns nothing. Surely you've seen in your textbook a method return a value (in this case void) based on a if condition!

Comment: Not sure if you are confused that it is not using brackets `{}`, if you only are using the `if` statement body for a single line you can just leave out the brackets.  They also just placed it on the same line, usually this is not good to do if you want easily readable code.  It can quickly get confusing, especially for loops.

Comment: the `return` just returns from the method; the `if` could have been written as `if (num < 0) { return; }` eventually with some newlines...

Comment: If I were to find this code, I would refactor it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short explanation:

If you just write return; you can stop the execution of the current method.

If statements don't need braces if they have a single statement following them like

```
if(2<variable)
   System.out.println("inIf")

System.out.println("outsideIf")
```

So.  `if (num < 0)  return;`

Just means: stop execution of method when number is smaller than 0
No other code in the method will be called

Comment: Ah Thank you! I got confused because of the return in a void function. I knew only from PHP like to stop execution of a script with die(); or similar...

Comment: No problem, return; only works in void functions, primitive functions like int,double need a value of the datatype like 0 or 0.0 and functions with Complex returntypes like MyObject can be stopped by returning null every time.

Answer (score 0):

After *if* follows a statement. Following is a valid code:

```
if (a > 5) b = c + 2;
```

Here *b = c + 2;* is a normal statement.

But statement can also defined by braces. You can use braces also in a normal code as follows:

```
long i = 3;
long j = 4;
long k = 9;

{ i = j + 7; }

{ i = i * k + 123; }

i = 345;

{ k = j * 10; }

{
  i = 234 * j; 
  k = 12 * j;
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Such form often makes no sense because it makes the code hard to understand :) But this is valid code which will correctly compile.

What you often see after *if* is just a statement like above.

Why do we see often braces after *if*?
After *if* exactly *one* statement is executed. If you have code like

```
if (a > 5)
b = c + 2;
k = i + 3;
```

then the statement *b = c + 2;* will be executed if the condition *a > 5* holds true. But the statement *k = i + 3;* will be executed *always*, independent on *a > 5*.

If you want *both* statements executed only if *a > 5* holds true, then you use braces:

```
if (a > 5) {
  b = c + 2;
  k = i + 3;
}
```

When you want to execute exactly one statement depending on *if*, you can omit braces. But your teammates in the project may be unsure if it was your intention to omit the braces or if it was just a mistake. To avoid any such doubts, coding guidelines in many projects require that *any* statement after *if* must use braces, no matter how simple the statement is.